# Basic on servlet

Tags: java, servlets

When do we implement Servlet Class and When do we implement GenricServlet class  as both of them are for life cycle methods?

and my sir told me that GenericServlet class is a helper class,so if we have to use GenricServlet class then whats the need of the Servlet interface?

Do we use Servlet class also without the help of GenricServlet?

Comment: `Do we use Servlet class also without the help of GenricServlet?` You can if you want to. Start by reading the javadoc of each of these types.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet is an interface and GenericServlet is a abstract class which implements Servlet, ServletConfig & Serializable.

GenericServlet class provides default implementation for all the methods in Servlet interface except the service method. So if you extends your servlet class from GenericServlet, you can only implements the service method and override those methods that you care about. It saves some time.

And of cause you can implement Servlet class without the help of GenericServlet.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet is an interface defining what a servlet should implement.

GenericServlet is a generic, protocol-independent servlet.

HttpServlet is a servlet tied specifically to the HTTP protocol.

when to use

In general, you'd extend HttpServlet to implement an application's web layer.

You can also implement Servlet if you're writing your own container or handling everything yourself.
 You can extend GenericServlet to handle a different protocol,by using the features provided by the container, but you might not.